# Go syntax highlighting for Coda 2?

Tags: go, syntax-highlighting, coda

Here's a list of existing third-party Coda-compatible syntax modes

http://www.codingmonkeys.de/subethaedit/modes.html

Has anyone stumbled upon a Go syntax mode for Coda 2?

Answer (score 0):

I could not find a Go syntax mode for Coda 2.

I didn't see one on GitHub or [this list of go syntax modes](http://go-lang.cat-v.org/text-editors/).

There is an existing [Go syntax mode feature request on the panic Q&A site](https://www.panic.com/qa/discussion/499/request-syntax-highlight-for-golang-mode/p1) that you can vote for though.